# How to utilize Webpack's bundle hash in a PHP backend?

Tags: php, html, webpack

I know and understand how/why cache busting works/is needed. In my situation, where my back-end code is in PHP and my front-end code is compiled in Webpack, how could I use Webpack's hashing method for cache busting purposes?

I can set up Webpack to output a hash alongside my filename, but how will I know which hash it outputted? How will I feed this hash to my back-end that generates the HTML code, so the correct asset bundle is loaded?

Comment: Not sure i understand corectly, but you want the new (style.css|bundle.js)?NEW_HASH to be available in your php layout after compilation ?

Comment: @darklightcode yes, something like that. when bundling webpack generates a hash and adds it to the file name, but I can't retrieve that hash programatically, so I could make a config file or something for my php backend to utilize when setting up the files for serving.

Comment: tell me, do you let `html-webpack-plugin` inject the assets in your layout file or you already have in your layout something like `<link href="style.css?<?php echo $extracted_hash ?>" />` ?

Comment: @darklightcode the second, webpack is only used to bundle the files.

Comment: I'll present two options, you choose which one would befit you. 
1. I have a similar stack, and i use `html-webpack-plugin` with only these options `{ template: path/to/layout.php", filename: path/to/layout.dist.php }`. `layout.dist.php` is in my .gitignore file, since the deployment takes place on another server. In my project i have a function that allows me to set the `default_layout` for views, in development it loads layout.php, but in production it loads layout.dist.php which contains all the hashed assets generated by webpack.

Comment: 2. This is kinda messy but it can be done. Webpack has a `compilation.done` function or something similar. When you reach this point, your new hashed file should already be present. You can then read the file with nodejs and parse the markup to `cheerio` (its like jquery, but for node) , and target an element with an ID (you set this on a hashable tag like <link /> or <script>) and substract the hashed value that html-webpack-plugin set on that tag#id element. Then write it in a separate file with nodejs.

Comment: I would suggest you go for the first option if you have a `default_layout` function, and create a wrapper around that to load the layout file for dev/prod based on some environment variable. Your local layout file will be alot cleaner since no link/script would reside there if you're using the webpack-dev-server.

Comment: For option 2, you might also find the hash in the stats object, i'm not sure about this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively hack-y solution:

You could write a function like this:

```
// Defined in: ./includes/functions.inc.php
function returnHashOfMainIn(string $dir): Maybe {
  
  // Get list of all files in given directory ($files is an array of strings).
  $files = scandir("../public/" . $dir); // (this line can be improved)

  // Handling possible failure.
  if ($files === false) {
    return Maybe::return(null); // returns a "Nothing" value.
    // Or simply return a false value if you don't like this typed approach.
  }
  
  // A filter function to discard files that don't start with "main".
  // (change this based on your need).
  $filterFn = function($item) {
    return substr($item, 0, 4) === "main";
  };
  
  // The filtered list of filenames.
  $filtered = array_values(array_filter($files, $filterFn));
  //          ^----------^
  // (used to reset array indices)
  
  if (count($filtered) <= 0) {
    return Maybe::return(null); // returns a "Nothing" value.
  } else {
    
    // Assuming a naming convention of `main.[contenthash].[ext]',
    // you can expect the hash occurring in resulting array's 1st index.
    $expd = explode(".", $filtered[0]);
    
    // Return a "Just string" value (or "Nothing" if $expd[1] is null)
    return Maybe::return($expd[1]);
  }
}
```

This basically gives you back the hash of the first encountered `main` file (you could just return the file name).

So assuming a `public` directory sits next to the `includes` directory (with `js` and `css` folders inside):

```
function makeJsTag() {
  $mJsHash = returnHashOfMainIn("js");
  $tag  = "<script src=\"./js/main.";
  $tag .= $mJsHash->getWithDefault("") . ".js\"></script>";
  return $tag;
}

function makeCssTag() {
  $mCssHash = returnHashOfMainIn("css");
  $tag  = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"./css/main.";
  $tag .= $mCssHash->getWithDefault("") . ".css\">";
  return $tag;
}
```

You could replace the filtering part with any other behavior as you desire (like sorting all found `main` files based on their last change time – using [`filectime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php)).

---

P.S. This is totally irrelevant, but for the sake of completeness, here's a possible definition of the `Maybe` type:

```
abstract class Maybe {
  abstract public function isJust();
  abstract public function getWithDefault($def);
  public static function return($val) {
    if (is_null($val)) {
      return new Nothing;
    } else {
      return new Just($val);
    }
  }
}

final class Just extends Maybe {
  private $value;
  public function __construct($value) {
    $this->value = $value;
  }
  public function isJust() {
    return true;
  }
  public function getWithDefault($_) {
    return $this->value;
  }
}

final class Nothing extends Maybe {
  public function isJust() {
    return false;
  }
  public function getWithDefault($def) {
    return $def;
  }
}
```